# How to choose apparent size/radius of geom point in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

When creating a geom points with ggplot

```
library(ggplot)

df=data.frame(x=1:10,y=1:10,s=1:10)
ggplot(df,aes(x,y,size=s))+geom_point()
```

The size of the points is "suggested" and fixed by default. Is there a simple way to link the radius of the points to the scale of x for example?

Comment: Maybe `+ scale_radius(range = range(df$x))`?